# GA Event tracking only works in external, target="_blank" links, not working in internal links nor mailto

Tags: google-analytics, mailto, internal-link

I'm implementing event tracking on my website and noticed it's only working in external, target blank links.

When I first put the code, 3 days ago, it worked on internal links and mailto as well. One day latter I decided to use a different set of values for Category, Action and Label and noticed GA stopped tracking internal links and mailto. Now I can only track external links, and it's been like this for the past 48 hours.

That's probably a noob problem, but I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a similar issue.

I'll appreciate any help. I'm reproducing the tracking code I'm using here:

**Mailto:**

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Text', 'Feedback', 'Bottom']);" href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.com">
```

**Internal link:**

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Text', 'Museos', 'Bottom']);" href="/wp/?page_id=XXXX ">
```

Comment: Both of those codes look correct. Have you used a tool like HTTPFox or Google Analytics Debugger to see if the event is firing? Any chance you could share the site?

Comment: Hi @Blexy, the site is [www.uniquevisitors.me](http://www.uniquevisitors.me). Please tell me if you can figure anything out. I'll take a look at the tools you suggested, thanks.

Comment: Hey @ana, I was able to look at your site using HTTPFox and clicked both the Mailto and internal link, and I was able to see them firing correctly. Do you see anything showing up in GA real-time reports? It should be.

Comment: You are right, @Blexy, it's working! I think the real time events report is not counting them like it does with other events, but if I wait a little longer they eventually show up at the regular events report.

The only links that are not being counted (or firing according to GA Debug for chrome) are the iPhone buttons both from the top and bottom of the homepage. I double checked the code and can’t figure it out. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like both buttons are firing according to GA Debug:[image]

Comment: Thanks @Blexy, I can see it at the reports now!